# How to improve visualisation of trajectories in 3D space

Tags: visualization, optics

I have a list of trajectories from a bunch of photons that travel inside a scattering medium. Each trajectory is a list of $(x,y,z)$ pairs. I'd like to visualise them in 3D space. I came up with the simplest (and ugliest) way:

```
data = Import["http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25202446/dat.3d", "List"];
data = ToExpression /@ data;
Graphics3D[Line /@ data, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

I also tried with `Point`s instead of connected lines but of course the result is also very "primitive".

Another idea was to use the `SmoothDensityHistogram[]` and `SmoothHistogram3D[]`  like this (I did some modifications in the code so that it works outside the context of my notebook. I hope that it does indeed):

```
plot1 = SmoothDensityHistogram[
   Take[#, 2] & /@ Flatten[data, 1],
       ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Ticks -> None, Frame -> False];

plot2 = SmoothHistogram3D[
    Take[#, 2] & /@ Flatten[data, 1],   
        ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, Ticks -> None, 
        Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];

comb = Style[Grid[{{plot1, plot2}}], ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

**NOTE**: The graphs that are generated may not look like entirely identical to the ones that I embedded, because the sample size is different.

[image]

Comment: It would be very helpful if you were to give us some idea of what you would consider as a satisfactory result. Without such guidance, I think your question is too vague.

Comment: Why do I only get [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgTdy.png)?

Comment: @Zet Ok you must have updated it, now it looks like c**p :)

Comment: @m_goldberg In all honesty, I don't really know. Something more colourful, smooth, that would give the hint where most photons travel. But I'm open to any idea, I wouldn't want to restrict people's imagination.

Comment: Do you specifically care about the *trajectories* or just the positions?

Comment: Can the data be made available again?  (The link no longer works.)

Answer (score 5):

You could create your own 3D density plot. Here's a simple example:

```
raw = Import["http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25202446/dat.3d", "List"];
data = ToExpression@raw;

rescaled = data /. Dispatch@With[{d = Flatten@data}, MapThread[Rule, {d, Rescale@d}]];
rounded = (unit = 100)*Round[rescaled, 1/(10 unit)] /. n_?NumericQ :> IntegerPart[n + 1];
tally = Tally@Flatten[rounded, 1];
tally[[All, 2]] = Rescale@tally[[All, 2]];
Graphics3D@{Raster3D[SparseArray[Rule @@@ tally], 
  ColorFunction -> {"HighRange", Min@tally[[All, 2]]/2}]}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not bad, not bad at all. Hm.

Answer (score 3):

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, Filling -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 600, 
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit"]
```

[image]

```
data = Flatten[ToExpression /@ 
    Import["http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25202446/dat.3d", "List"], 1];

Histogram[Transpose@data, ImageSize -> 600, ChartLegends -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[data, ImageSize -> 600, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", ViewPoint -> Right, 
 Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> White, 
 AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y", "Z"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is that a subtle cheer for italy?

Comment: @Yves - por Mexico, naturalmente :)

Comment: Thanks @eldo for taking the time to write up an answer! The "problem" with the last one is that it colors based on the value of the coordinates, not based on the density of the points (I think).

Comment: @zet - that's true. My personal difficulty with your nice question is the following: You speak of a "bunch of photons". Where is the "bunch" in your data? I assumed that all points are different photons with their xyz-coordinates measured at one point of time with a "photon clock". If so, you cannot connect them with lines because they are different entities. If I am wrong (let's assume there are 100 time-trajectories of 1000 photones), you would need a 4D-screen after having overcome the "Uncertainty principle".